# This app has 4 unprocessed crashes. Upload 1 dSYM file to process them

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

i have a flutter app which is connected to crashlytics, on android crashlytics works normally, but for ios, i get the following error

[image]

I've tried uploading dsyms with this method
xcode->product->archive->choose build->show in finder-> show package content
and get a success alert like this

```
Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols
```

but when checked on crashlytics, there is still the same error, please help

Comment: Wait a couple of hours, processing takes time.

Comment: how long sir ? i try upload dsyms yesterday

Comment: For me it usually resolves in a couple of hours, but it's not a timing issue in your case, judging from your response.

Comment: For this to work, the UUID of the dSYM file has to match the UUID shown in the Crashltyics dashboard, even if the upload is successful.  Do they match?